# Tcl/Tk - How to keep other buttons useable while separate function still running?

Tags: sockets, server, client, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm very new to Tcl/Tk and have been dealing with an issue for the last couple of days. Basically I have a server written in C and a client GUI written in Tcl/Tk. So far it doesn't do a ton. To test it, I start up the server so that it's listening for connections, then run my GUI. When I click one of the buttons, the GUI should open up a separate toplevel window with a text widget embedded in it. (This part works.) Then, my client connects to the server and gives it a couple of settings, and through this the server decides what info to send back. The server's response is what gets printed to that second window's text widget.

What I'm trying to add in now is a Stop button. Right now, my server is set up to wait a couple of seconds, then write the same message to the client. This is set up inside a loop that is waiting to hear a "Stop" command from my client. I have a Stop button in the GUI with a command set up to write that command to the server when clicked. However, all of my buttons get frozen as soon as I hit the begin button and messages are written to the client.

Basically, how can I keep allowing my server to write to my client while still keeping the rest of my GUI usable? I want my client to write a new line to the text widget on my separate window whenever it receives a new message from the server, but I still want the main GUI window that has all my command buttons to behave independently.

Comment: What have you tried so far and are you able to share any code samples? Also consider removing unnecessary information so that it's easier to read/understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

In general, it depends on whether what you are doing is CPU-intensive (where reading from a plain file counts as CPU-intensive) or I/O-intensive (where running things in another process counts as I/O-intensive; database calls often count as CPU-intensive here despite not really needing to). I'm only going to mention summaries of what's going on as you aren't quite providing enough information.

For I/O-intensive code, you want to structure your code to be event-driven. Tcl has good tools for this, in that `fileevent` works nicely on sockets, terminals and pipelines on all supported platforms. The [`coroutine` system](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/coroutine) of Tcl 8.6 can help a lot with preventing the callbacks required from turning your code into a tangled mess!

For CPU-intensive code, the main option is to run in another thread. That thread won't be able to touch the GUI directly (which in turn will be free to be responsive), but will be able to do all the work and send messages back to the main thread with whatever UI updates it wants done. (*Technically* you can do this with I/O-intensive code too, but it's more irritating than using a coroutine.) Farming things out to a subprocess is just another variation on this where the communications are more expensive (but much isolation is enforced by the OS).

---

If you're dealing with sockets, you're *probably* I/O-intensive. Assume that until you show otherwise. Here's a simple example:

```
proc gets_async {sock} {
    set sock [lindex $args end]
    fileevent $sock readable [info coroutine]
    while {[gets $sock data] < 0 && [fblocked $sock]} {
        yield
    }
    fileevent $sock readable {}
    return $data
}

proc handler {socket} {
    set n 0
    while {![eof $socket]} {
        # Write to the server
        puts $socket "this is message [incr n] to the server"
        # Read from the server
        puts [gets_async $socket]
    }
    close $socket
}

proc launchCommunications {host port} {
    set sock [socket $host $port]
    fconfigure $sock -blocking 0 -encoding utf-8
    coroutine comms($host:$port) handler $socket
}
```

Note that `gets_async` is much like `coroutine::util gets` in [Tcllib](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/coroutine/tcllib_coroutine.md).